# Cant get a database connection as I cant pass context to DBManager

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have a Dummy Data manager that will populate an ArrayList with the content of a SQLite database.  When I try to create a DB object I get an error stating Says 'com.example.listview.manager.ActivityDummyDataManager.this' cannot be referenced from a static context.

```
package com.example.listview.manager;

import android.database.Cursor;
import com.example.listview.DBManager;
import com.example.listview.model.ActivityItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ActivityDummyDataManager {


    public static ArrayList<ActivityItem> getActivityItemList() {
        DBManager db = new DBManager(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.fetch();
        ArrayList<com.example.listview.model.ActivityItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int index;
            index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id");
            Long id = cursor.getLong(index);

            index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("activity");
            String activity = cursor.getString(index);

            index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description");
            String description = cursor.getString(index);

            index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("description");
            String date = cursor.getString(index);
            ActivityItem item = new ActivityItem();
            item.setId(id);
            item.setActivity(activity);
            item.setDescription(description);
            item.setDate(date);
            list.add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

I have a DBManager class I would normally access using DBManager db = new DBManager(this) but for some reason, this will not work from this class.

```
package com.example.listview;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBManager {
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DBManager(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {

        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert(String activity, String description, String date) {
        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY, activity);
        contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, description);
        contentValue.put(DatabaseHelper.DATE, date);
        database.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValue);
    }

    public Cursor fetch() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                DatabaseHelper._ID,
                DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY,
                DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION,
                DatabaseHelper.DATE
        };
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null,
                null, null, null, "DATE DESC");
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetchForEdit(String id) {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                DatabaseHelper._ID,
                DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY,
                DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION,
                DatabaseHelper.DATE
        };

        String [] args = new String [] {id};
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, "_ID=?",
              args, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        Log.d("DATABASE", "cursor= "+cursor.getColumnName(1));
        return cursor;
    }


    public int update(long _id, String activity, String description, String date) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY, activity);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, description);
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DATE, date);
        int i = database.update(
                DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
                DatabaseHelper._ID + " = " + _id,
                null);
        return i;
    }

    public void delete(long _id) {
        database.delete(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                DatabaseHelper._ID + "=" + _id,
                null);
    }
}
```

Why can't I set the DBManager db = new DBManager(this); to get a DB connection.
Says 'com.example.listview.manager.ActivityDummyDataManager.this'
cannot be referenced from a static context.
Could someone also explain the context argument as I don't really understand it.

Comment: you can initiate a dbManger directly. with out any context reference. either you have to call getApplicationContext() or class level context you need to call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Constructor  `DBManager(Context c)` expects a context as parameter, If you call this constructor from Activity or Service class it will work as both Activity and Service are sub-classes of Context, So passing `this` should suffice. As `ActivityDummyDataManager` does not handle context you need to pass Context either from activity or you can pass application context `getApplicationContext()`.

Change your method as below

```
public static ArrayList<ActivityItem> getActivityItemList() {
        DBManager db = new DBManager(mContext);
        //rest of your code.
}
```

and while calling it use activity or application context whichever is suitable.

Comment: Get Non-static method 'getApplicationContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: update your `getActivityItemList(Context context)` while calling and pass activity context from wherever you call it and use this context in method code as well.